# How do I filter results and then count them in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need four different counts: the total number of results and then the number of results in three categories. For example, if I have four students and I want them sorted by grade, I want: (1) the total number of students, (2) the total number of students in grade 1, (3) the total number of students in grade 2, (4) the total number of students in grade 3. If I have student nodes where s.grade=1, s.grade=1, s.grade=2, and s.grade=3, is there a way to get a result that returns only what I want and no other information correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This does not include the total number of students, but here is one way you could aggregate the number of students in each grade:

```
START n=node(*) 
WHERE HAS(n.grade) AND n.grade > 0 AND n.grade <= 3
RETURN DISTINCT n.grade AS grade, count(n.grade) AS count
```

Depending on what your schema/structure is, you'll probably need to filter `n` down to be only students.